# How to use Relay Response URL in Authorize.NET Payment Gateway?

Tags: authorize.net

I am currently working on integrating my sample site with Authorize.NET.

So I created a Sandbox account in Authorize.NET.

Using this test account, I am testing DPM and using Relay Response URL.

First, my page is Confirm.aspx which contains the credit card details.

On submitting the Page, it will be redirected to the `test url:https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll`.

I am setting the **x_relay_response="TRUE"; x_relay_url="http://localhost:3489/SIM.aspx";**

**My Question and Confusion is:**

To which page the relay response will be received and for me it is simply throwing some error or warning. I will post the screen capture of my issue. kindly provide your valuable suggestions or solutions that would be appreciable.

The screenshot is shown below:

[image: error on setting relay response url]

Comment: Also use a webservice not a web page

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving an error because your relay response URL is not publicly available and the sandbox is unable to connect to it.

[Relay Response Basics and Troubleshooting](http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/forums/searchpage/tab/message?filter=labels,location&location=blog-board%3aDeveloperBlog&q=relay%20response)

Comment: I am working in a test environment. Then how can I check the relay Response Url? Is this the cause for error? is there any solution to it?

Comment: The solution is to expose your relay response URL for the sandbox post.

Comment: You should be able to use a tool like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) and expose your local URL to the public without a lot of hassle during development. The free version works sufficiently well when dealing with this issue now and then.